# Problem: Tabbar Controller + Navigation Controller: Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

**Hello guys,**

I trying to make a app with tabbar controller and navigation controller.
But i get some problems...  When i try to popViewController on my second view, the app crash.
Some one knows what's going on?

**My Delegate:**

```
// -- PranchetaAppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    PlayersViewController* playersViewController = [[PlayersViewController alloc] initWithTabBar];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:playersViewController];

    [localControllersArray addObject:self.navigationController];

    [self.navigationController release];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;
    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self.navigationController release];
    [localControllersArray release];

    return YES;

}
```

**My First View:**

```
// -- PlayersViewsController.m

- (id)initWithTabBar {

    if (self)
    {

        self.title = @"Players";
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PlayersTabBarIcon.png"];

        CustomNavigationBarButton *addButtonView = [[CustomNavigationBarButton alloc] initWithImage:@"AddButton.png" withSelected:@"AddButtonSelected.png"];

        [addButtonView addTarget:self action:@selector(gotoCreatePlayers) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:addButtonView];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

        [addButton release];
        [addButtonView release];

    }

    return self;

}

- (void)gotoCreatePlayers {

    CreatePlayersViewController *createPlayer = [CreatePlayersViewController new];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:createPlayer animated:YES];
    [createPlayer release];

}
```

When i push my second view, i try to go back into the navigation. But the app crash...

**Error appointed:**

```
// --  main.m
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

change:

```
CreatePlayersViewController *createPlayer = [CreatePlayersViewController new];
```

to:

```
CreatePlayersViewController *createPlayer = [CreatePlayersViewController alloc];
```

also if there are any init methods to call than it should look like this

```
CreatePlayersViewController *createPlayer = [[CreatePlayersViewController alloc]init];
```

try somthing like this:
ADD THIS TO THE .h FILE: `CreatePlayersViewController *createPlayer`
then replace your code above with this:

```
if (createPlayer ==nil) {
    CreatePlayersViewController *nextView = [[CreatePlayersViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.createPlayer = nextView;
    [nextView release];
}
self.meetTheTeam.view.hidden = NO;


[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.meetTheTeam animated:YES];
```

Comment: Doesnt work... I will create the navigation controller, inside of my first view controller.

Comment: your section "error appointed" is probably a "bad access" error.  which means your tring to write or read from an area of memory your not suppose to be in.  ill look over the code again though and see anything else that might b wrong

Comment: check my edits.  ur getting an error, i had a problem were the view wouldnt load. thats why the hidden=no is there

Comment: Sorry man, i don't understand what do you want to me do. Create meetTheTeam Class? Can i use my exist class: CreatePlayersViewController?

Comment: create a variable in your .h file CreatePlayersViewController *createPlayer.  ill edit the code above to make it look how u want it to.   FYI just replace the code where your trying to change views (not the whole class)

Comment: I find da error! I just release bar button item that was autoreleased!

    [doneButton autorelease];

Thx! For the help Owen Gerig!